Periodic bang on bike freewheel
First of all, this is a great community :)
I have bought a trek FX 1 Stagger recently, and there is one problem which I’m not sure how to address.
There is a noise coming out of the freewheel whenever it is underload.
I've recorded a video with the sound: https://youtube.com/shorts/ZYq48HVEU2s?feature=share
Here are the facts:

The noise happens while the freewheel is under load. But only on back gears 4-5-6.
Front gears do not affect the noise.
More load means more noise.
The noise is period and its period seems to be proportional to the rotation speed of the free wheel.

EDIT: After following some of the suggestions below, I think I've narrowed down the problem to a loose hub/freewheel. See the following video: https://youtube.com/shorts/hrRQ1aJRIeA?feature=share
At least the sound is very similar to the one I hear while pedaling.
EDIT2: Thank you for all the comments and suggestions! The problem went away after replacing the free wheel. It was defective.
I really appreciate any help. Thank you!

The noise appears to be in-time with the wheel RPMs - that suggests something is hitting something else.   Does the noise continue and slow if you stop pedalling and coast?

Can you replicate the noise if you lift the rear wheel off the ground and "air-pedal" while standing still ?

Thank you for your very pertinent questions @Criggie :).
The noise stops if I pedal with no load (very slight pressure only) or coasting.

Can you replicate the noise if you lift the rear wheel off the ground and "air-pedal" while standing still ?

This is a very good question. I can reproduce it when having the bike on a stand. Rotating the pedals with force is enough to reproduce it. BUT I haven't tried it with the bike flipped over.

When turning the pedals by hand, on a stand or with the bike upside down, keep a close eye on the rear derailleur. Does it twitch at all. Also, does the wheel appear to wobble, either pedalling or pushing it by hand

Based on the description, something's really weird with your bike.
Noise is related to pedalling hard and stops when coasting which suggests the cause is related to parts that move during pedalling but stay still during coasting.
I would pull the wheel out of the bike and have a close look at the cassette/cogs.
There may be some slop where the hub or cogs move under pedalling load but not when coasting AND that is somehow touching a moving part of the wheel.
Since the noise stops when coasting, its unlikely to be the frame.   Mudguard appears to have plenty of space.
Try lightly dragging the rear brake while riding and see if that has any effect.
I also see your bike has one of those rear wheel locks - make sure that's fully retracted too and that the key is not dangling.
IF the bike was in the biggest rear cog (the lowest gear) I might wonder if the derailleur or its cable housing is somehow touching a spoke on every revolution.
Idea If you have access to any other wheel, try swapping for a test.  Even if its a poor match for gears and brakes etc, just mount a spare wheel and spin it in place.   Another idea is to flip your current wheel in the dropouts and see what happens.  Of course you can't pedal but the tyre should be centered on the midline between the dropouts.
Inspect the tread of the tyre and see if there's any bulges or wear areas.  Sometimes the thin sprues can cause noise too.
Dumb idea - are your yellow wheel reflectors loose?  I remove them and use white clip-on spoke reflectors personally, but maybe one is moving under high wheel RPMs?

Thank you so much! This is a very helpful set of ideas. Will report back the result of my experiments as soon as I have some time!

I have had interference happen only while pedalling, that was caused bythe frame. But first, very loose hub bearings  can do that as pedalling pulls the wheel into a different position (my tyre was rubbing on my chainstay for that reason the other day, underlying cause probably a bent axle). A broken chainstay/dropout weld led to noise on every right pedal stroke. But in both cases it's in time with the pedal rotation, not the wheel rotation

I think that something is definitely too loose @ChrisH . Thanks for the suggestion. See my above edit please.

The freewheel does look loose.  I wonder if the axle feels loose too
